# My script is only executed to the first element on my dataframe Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need your help on a loop here:

I have a dataframe df that looks like this:

```
    OC  OZ  ON  WT  DC  DZ  DN
0   PL  97  TP  59  DE  63  DC 
1   US  61  SU  95  US  95  SU
2   SA  32  FS  57  DQ  09  PO
3   QS  54  FS  13  HR  78  LK
4   DQ  76  DS  65  SQ  94  PO
```

I have some operations that works for the first row and would like to automate it to the rest of the dataframe.

*** Expected Output***

```
    OC  OZ  ON  WT  DC  DZ  DN  VALUE
0   PL  97  TP  59  DE  63  DC  1800
1   US  61  SU  95  US  95  SU  9819
2   SA  32  FS  57  DQ  09  PO  8721
3   QS  54  FS  13  HR  78  LK  6721
4   DQ  76  DS  65  SQ  94  PO  3432
```

This whole works for the first row, but cannot be executed for the whole dataframe:

```
dic = {}
dic['section'] = []
for ix, row in df_road.iterrows():
    in_dict1 = {'location': 
        {
        'zipCode': 
            {'country': row['OC'],
            'code': row['OZ']},
        'location': {'id': '1'}, 
        'longName': row['ON'],  
            },
    'carriageParameter': 
         {'road': 
              {'truckLoad': 'Auto'}
            },
    'load': 
         {'weight': str(row['WT']),
          'unit': 'ton',
          'showEmissionsAtResponse': 'true'
         }
    }
    in_dict2 = {'location': 
        {
        'zipCode': 
            {'country': row['DC'],
            'code': row['DZ']},
        'location': {'id': '2'}, 
        'longName': row['DN']
        },
        'carriageParameter':
             {'road': 
                 {'truckLoad': 'Auto'}
            },      
        'unload': {
            'weight': str(row['WT']),
            'unit': 'ton',
            'showEmissionsAtResponse': 'true'
        }
        }
    dic['section'].append(in_dict1)
    dic['section'].append(in_dict2)
    request_data=dict({'section':'',
    'customer':'XXXX',
    'password':'XXXX',
    'showRoute':'true'})
    section_data = dict(dic)
    request_data.update(section_data)
    print(request_data)
    result = client.service.calculateDistribution(**request_data)
    result = serialize_object(result.result) 
    df = pd.json_normalize(result)
```

Comment: Check DataFrame.apply: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: Thanks @MohitMotwani for the apply function hint. How could it be used on my code ?

Comment: Write a function that you would like to apply to each row and use apply. It will do the rest. You don’t need to use a for loop. The documentation is pretty comprehensive, will be easy for you to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the issue.

The problem was that i had to instantiate the `dic = {}` and `dic['section'] = []` inside the loop.

Below the final code that works.

```
for ix, row in df_road.iterrows():
    in_dict1 = {'location':
    dic = {}
    dic['section'] = []
        {
        'zipCode': 
            {'country': row['OC'],
            'code': row['OZ']},
        'location': {'id': '1'}, 
        'longName': row['ON'],  
            },
    'carriageParameter': 
         {'road': 
              {'truckLoad': 'Auto'}
            },
    'load': 
         {'weight': str(row['WT']),
          'unit': 'ton',
          'showEmissionsAtResponse': 'true'
         }
    }
    in_dict2 = {'location': 
        {
        'zipCode': 
            {'country': row['DC'],
            'code': row['DZ']},
        'location': {'id': '2'}, 
        'longName': row['DN']
        },
        'carriageParameter':
             {'road': 
                 {'truckLoad': 'Auto'}
            },      
        'unload': {
            'weight': str(row['WT']),
            'unit': 'ton',
            'showEmissionsAtResponse': 'true'
        }
        }
    dic['section'].append(in_dict1)
    dic['section'].append(in_dict2)
    request_data=dict({'section':'',
    'customer':'XXXX',
    'password':'XXXX',
    'showRoute':'true'})
    section_data = dict(dic)
    request_data.update(section_data)
    print(request_data)
    result = client.service.calculateDistribution(**request_data)
    result = serialize_object(result.result) 
    df = pd.json_normalize(result)
```